# http-api Яндекса для поиска подсказок

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите, существует ли публичное http-api для получения подсказок к вводимому(в поле ввода) адресу? Если нет, планируется ли предоставление такого апи?

P.S.
Про альтернативу использования фронтовых библиотек(js, android/ios) знаем.

Comment: "планируется ли предоставление такого апи"... это вопрос к Яндексу, очевидно...

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент HTTP-версии для функции [Suggest](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest.html) у Яндекса нет. Использование недокументированных возможностей является нарушением [пользовательского соглашения](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/), поэтому для любых бизнес-решений подобные действия неприменимы как минимум.

Что касается планов, то, даже при наличии подобных, Яндекс вроде бы никогда не анонсировал продукты до момента хотя бы их бета-тестирования. Это касается не только сроков, но и планов реализации в целом. Не думаю, что тут может быть исключение.

Новости же можно отслеживать в [Клубе API Карт](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi). Скорее всего подобная информация появится там в первую очередь.